# 3D rotational matrix between two spherical co-ordinate systems.

Tags: matrices, rotations, spherical-coordinates

So I have a classical mechanics problem where I have worked out the azimuthal and altitude angle for a vector, I then want to apply rotational matrices so that the vector is realigned with the z axis only. i.e. I want to turn a spherical co-ordinate (r, $\theta$,$\phi$) into Euler rotations

To do this I think I need to do

\begin{alignat}{1}
R_z(\phi) &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \phi &  -\sin \phi & 0 \\[3pt]
\sin \phi & \cos \phi & 0\\[3pt]
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
then\\
R_y(\theta) &= \begin{bmatrix}
\cos \theta & 0 & \sin \theta \\[3pt]
0 & 1 & 0 \\[3pt]
-\sin \theta & 0 & \cos \theta \\
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
then\\
R(\psi) &= \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \cos \psi &  -\sin \psi \\[3pt]
0 & \sin \psi  &  \cos \psi \\[3pt]
\end{bmatrix} \\[6pt]
\end{alignat}

But I don't know how to work out $\psi$ for this as the first rotation is about the z axis and so rotates the x and y axis, and then the second matrix only rotates around the y axis, but the angle $\theta$ in spherical co-ordinates is not about the y axis only but x and y at the same time depending on the angle $\phi$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You're probably having problems because any single vector can be rotated to another vector in terms of one rotation, or even just two rotations about Cartesian axes.  I think to decompose into *three* rotations, your problem is underdetermined.

Comment: Yes I agree, but I don't know which two matrices will work.

Answer (score 1):

If I start with a vector in the z direction

\begin{alignat}{1}
V &=|V| \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\[3pt]
0\\[3pt]
1\\
\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
\end{alignat}

then $R_z(\phi)R_y(\theta)V$

I get
\begin{alignat}{1}
V_{new} &=|V| \begin{bmatrix}
\sin\theta\cos\phi \\[3pt]
\sin\theta\sin\phi\\[3pt]
\cos\theta\\
\end{bmatrix}\\[6pt]
\end{alignat}

Which happens to be the right form for the spherical co-ordinate. Can anyone see why this would be wrong in general?

Comment: Indeed, in the [physics convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system) a latitude rotation will take you to the proper parallel (latitude) and a longitude rotation will subsequently take you to the desired meridian. You may reverse these rotations on fixed axes to go back to the North pole.